# SQL - Converting one value into two or more possible values

Tags: sql, hive

I have one table I would like to convert into another set of values.

| Table A's Letter Column | Converts into |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA AND AB |
| B | BB |
| C | CC |

So, what I am doing is...

1. SELECT all the values from Table A
2. Convert Table A's values using a CASE

```
CASE TABLE A COLUMN
 WHEN 'A' THEN 'AA'
 WHEN 'A' THEN 'AB'
 WHEN 'B' THEN 'BB'
 WHEN 'C' THEN 'CC'
 ELSE NULL
END
```

Of course, a CASE statement can only have one outcome and thus I can't get it show both 'AA' and 'AB' when it converts 'A' from Table A. What can I do in this situation?

The expected outcome I want is that it would show (AA, AB, BB, and CC) using the input of (A, B, and C).

Let me know if this sounds confusing!
Thank you!

EDIT: For clarification... I modified the orignal above and added details below.

1. I have three values that I pulled from one table using a SELECT.
2. I want these three values to be shown in the converted form as 'AA', 'AB', 'BB', and 'CC'.

Comment: sounds quite confusing as to what you are trying to achieve as outcome.

Comment: Understandable... Maybe I'll start from scratch.

1) I have one table, let's call it CAB. It has multiple instances of the same value: 'A', 'B', 'C' under column DAB.
2) I then wanted to select only the unique values from 'DAB'... SELECT UNIQUE(DAB) FROM CAB
3) Afterwards, I would to convert the values in the CAB table into other values. 'A' -> 'AA', 'B'->'BB' and 'C'->'CC'. However, 'A' also has other possible values it can also be. 'A' can be 'AA' and 'AB'. There is no second table that holds these secondary values (AA, AB, BB, CC) 
4) I want final results to appear as AA, AB, BB, CC

Answer (score 1):

You would do this with an additional table and join. So you have table to map the `Letter` column from TableA to the desired outputs:

| Letter | MappedValue |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA |
| A | AB |
| B | BB |
| C | CC |

**OR**

| Letter | MappedValue |
| --- | --- |
| A | AA,AB |
| B | BB |
| C | CC |

Now you can bring this in with a `JOIN`. Note that you should **strongly prefer the first option**. Delimited data in a column is rarely, if ever, the right choice. However, I'm more of a Sql Server guy, and I'm not sure what Hive has in place of Sql Server's `string_agg()`, which you need in order to avoid spreading the results over multiple records.

Additionally, if you are unable to create the table, Sql Server has a feature called [Table Value Constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) that can used to include this mapping directly in the single SQL statement. This feature is actually part of the ansi standard, but it's one of those parts of the standard that tend to get lost by some of the more recent SQL-like projects and again: I'm not sure how it will look in Hive.

Comment: I was afraid that might be the case. I didn't want to resort to creating a new table entirely and then joining it. I'll have to see if I have any work access to create any sorts of table whether temporary or with Table Value Constructors. I would be using your first output with the AA and AB separated in their own rows and then try to join it.

I'll see what happens when I try again tomorrow! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can join with subquery:

```
with mytable as (--this is example, use your table instead mytable CTE
select 'A' letter union all
select 'B' letter union all
select 'C' letter
)

select t.letter, conv.conv
  from mytable t
       inner join (--conversion data
                   select 'A' letter, 'AA' conv union all
                   select 'A' letter, 'AB' conv union all
                   select 'B' letter, 'BB' conv union all
                   select 'C' letter, 'CC' conv
                  ) conv on t.letter=conv.letter
```

Result:

```
letter   conv
A        AA
A        AB
B        BB
C        CC
```